# Wandb-Error : AttributeError: can't set attribute 'model'

Tags: transfer-learning, wandb

I am currently working on a transfer learning project using the EfficientNet model and I want to log into wandb to save the model history for comparison.

Unfortunately, I encountered an error. Previously, I used wandb for end-to-end model building, so now I am quite confused and cannot find a solution for this case.

Could you please help me with this? Thank you very much.

This is my code and error:

```
efficientnet_base = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

efficientnet_base.trainable = False

X_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

X = efficientnet_base(X_input)

X = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='valid', name='AvgPool2D')(X)
X = Flatten(name='Flatten')(X)
X = Dense(200, activation='relu', name='Dense1')(X)
X = Dropout(0.1)(X)
X = Dense(100, activation='relu', name='Dense2')(X)
X = Dropout(0.1)(X)
X = Dense(6, activation='softmax', name='Dense3')(X)  

model = Model(inputs=X_input, outputs=X, name='Fruit_Classifer')

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)

model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
_ = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data = validation_ds, epochs = 5, batch_size = 32,
             callbacks=[WandbCallback(data_type="image", generator=validation_ds), early_stopping])
```

Error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[54], line 4
      1 optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)
      3 model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
----> 4 _ = model.fit(train_ds, validation_data = validation_ds, epochs = 5, batch_size = 32,
      5              callbacks=[WandbCallback(data_type="image", generator=validation_ds), early_stopping])

AttributeError: can't set attribute 'model'
```

Comment: From w&b here, can you post the full trace?